# How to append to json object

Tags: python, json

I have the following code to create a JSON file from all my cisco devices in the company. All devices have either 2021 or 2022 in their name. so I have 2 loops to count them all and save as json file:

```
json_object = {}
for i in idf:
    for device in data:
        if "2021" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if device[-4:-2] == i:
                json_object[i] = {'2021': device }

        if "2022" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if len(device) >= 18:
                if device[:-2].isdigit():
                    if device[:-2] == i:
                        json_object[i] = {'2022': device }


        print(json_object)
```

The problem is, it only saves the last iterate in the loop. It is finding all devices, but it is replacing the items in the JSON object. **I need to APPEND the data for each LOOP**

How can I do that?

Comment: what is the purpose of your first loop? what is in `idf`? can you put a sample?

Comment: I would guess that you want: `{ '2021': [dev1, dev2, ...], '2022': [deva, devb, ...] }` but you haven't clearly stated what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this? I have added a comment at the end of each added/modified line.

```
json_object = {}
for i in idf:
    json_objects[i] = []  # line added
    for device in data:
        if "2021" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if device[-4:-2] == i:
                json_object[i] += [{'2021': device }]  # line modified

        if "2022" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if len(device) >= 18:
                if device[:-2].isdigit():
                    if device[:-2] == i:
                        json_object[i] += [{'2022': device }]  # line modified
```

The idea is that, for each `i`, you will want to create a list in which you will add your values. For each iteration, you `append` to that list by doing `json_object[i] += ...`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to do that:

```py
json_object = {}
for i in idf:
    for device in data:
        if "2021" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if device[-4:-2] == i:
                json_object.setdefault(i, []).append({'2021': device })

        if "2022" in device and device[-4:].isdigit():
            if len(device) >= 18:
                if device[:-2].isdigit():
                    if device[:-2] == i:
                        json_object.append({'2022': device })
```